# SQL query to select a User's friends via an associated model

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

My question is: for a given User, what SQL command could be used to select
all associated initiators/initiatees for which the associated Relation is confirmed and of a given type?

The Ruby is as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relations
end

class Relation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :initiator, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :initiatee, class_name: "User"
end

class CreateRelations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table    :relations do |t|
      t.references  :initiator
      t.references  :initiatee
      t.boolean     :is_confirmed, default: false
      t.integer     :type
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You want the SQL, not the rails methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to run into trouble because Rails expects `type` to be used for [Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html). You also need to tell Rails that the ID on `relations` is not `user_id`, which will be the default for `has_many`. Since you have two directions of relationship, you're going to need to declare both.

```
  has_many :outgoing_relations, class_name: 'Relation', foreign_key: 'initiator_id'
  has_many :incoming_relations, class_name: 'Relation', foreign_key: 'initiatee_id'
```

From there, the simplest thing to do is write a method that aggregates the other users:

```
def friends(params = {})
  outgoing_relations.where(params).includes(:initiatee).map(&:initiatee) +
  incoming_relations.where(params).includes(:initiator).map(&:initiator)
end
```

```
> User.first.friends(is_confirmed: true, kind: 0)
=> [#<User id: 2, created_at: "2015-08-28 15:11:12", updated_at: "2015-08-28 15:11:12">]
```

In straight SQL, you can easily `UNION` a couple queries to pull the other user IDs that you want, then do what you like with them.

```sql
SELECT initiatee_id AS id
FROM relations
WHERE initiator_id = 2
  AND kind = 0
  AND is_confirmed
UNION
SELECT initiator_id AS id
FROM relations
WHERE initiatee_id = 2
  AND kind = 0
  AND is_confirmed
;
```

```
 id
----
  1
  3
```

This is the data I'm running on:

```
SELECT * FROM users;
 id |         created_at         |         updated_at
----+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 | 2015-08-28 15:11:10.631187 | 2015-08-28 15:11:10.631187
  2 | 2015-08-28 15:11:12.911575 | 2015-08-28 15:11:12.911575
  3 | 2015-08-28 15:14:27.762946 | 2015-08-28 15:14:27.762946

SELECT * FROM relations;
 id | initiator_id | initiatee_id | is_confirmed | kind
----+--------------+--------------+--------------+------
  1 |            1 |            2 | t            |    0
  2 |            3 |            2 | t            |    0
```